# How do I optimize serial communication for large data strings?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm working with an Arduino Uno and WS2812b LED stripes.

**What I'm trying to do:**

So I've a 12 x 10 grid of LEDs and I've made a software that maps these LEDs to a texture of the same size, which I can draw to.
I now want to make multiple textures and send them one by one to the arduino to create something like an animation, so that I don't have to code the pixel positions by myself.

**The problem:**

If I just sent this data over as numbers in a string, I'd need 120 * 12 Bytes = 1440 Bytes for the buffer size.
I've tried to convert the numbers into hex values. But then I still need 960 Bytes for the buffer.
Any higher bases won't help here, because even with base36 I'd need 2 characters to represent 255.

**My approaches:**

- I can change the buffer size for the Arduino to 960 but then the RAM is
  99% used up and the arduino software tells me that stability problems
  can occour and I guess that is happening, because this approach does
  not work.
- Another approach was to use ASCII characters for each value from 0 to
  255. That could reduce the total amount of bytes to 480 but the Arduino only knows 128 and the first 32 are taken by the
  system.
- I've also tried to send the data sequentially with different buffer sizes but the serial communication is to slow. You can see how it "draws" the image from top to bottom. So I really want to draw it all at once.

Can I somehow extend the ASCII character table or make my own?
Or can I send the raw byte data over to the arduino  instead of using strings/char arrays?

Or do you have other approaches? I'm really curious.

Comment: What is your rate? Arduino sure can support 115200bps which can send your image in less than 100ms or 10 fps.

Comment: @Jellyboy I've tried it with 115200bps and sending the data over from C# at 60 fps but it still takes pretty long for the image to draw (to long for the human eye to not notice), since I have to send it sequentially and when I update for example the first row but the loop is already in the second row, I have to wait for all other rows to be processed to update the first again.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with arduino. Can't you just send the data as-is (in binary form)? Encoding/decoding to readable characters seems like unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Gene didn't found any better way other than recieving a char array on the arduino side.

Comment: @Buttermilch Can you just compare the two images in sequence and only set the pixels that changed?

Comment: Don't use any encoding - send bytes as bytes. You need to send `1440 Bytes`, no more, no less. `do you have other approaches?` Use a greater board - as you found out, you're at it's limits. When by it, research VNC and it's compression algorithms.

Comment: @Jellyboy yup but in the worst case the whole image will change and then I have the same problem again.

Comment: @Buttermilch is that an RGB image or ON/OFF pixels?

Comment: @Jellyboy it's RGB. And each LED has an index. That's why I need 12 Bytes for each LED. I could just use 4 Bytes with 3 for the index and 1 for on/off but then I can only control the LED color on the arduino... but as KamilCuk already said in his comment, I've reached the limits of the board and I'll propbaly go with the 4 Byte approach. That reduces the total amount to  480

Comment: `char` arrays can contain 8 bits of binary data per character.  Encoding those bits in some other form doesn't add any value I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGB has 3 bytes and addressing a single led of 120 takes 1 byte. Why you believe that it takes 12 byte instead of 4? Maybe you have to add some internal index to real address translation.

And if you send always all pixels, there is no need to send the address at all. Makes 360 bytes + some start sync which can be a "break" on the serial line.

At 115200 this will end by around 30 fps.

In addition you can take some "packing" like sending a color map once before and select with 1 byte from a color map of 256 colors which ends in 90 fps.

Comment: You're right. I've sent 12 bytes previously, because on the arduino side it was much easier to read a char array. And with the index and  r, g, b values everything added up to 12 Bytes per LED.

But I have now realized, that I don't need the index at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have now a more or less good solution.

I just send over the LED index as a hex string combined with a char that tells me if it turns on or off.
That reduces the total amount to 360 Bytes but I can only set the colors on the arduino side.

Comment: You should be able to send binary directly, there's no need to encode in hex. Is there a reason why you need to send the indices? Maybe you could send just an array of colors? Assuming you need 3 bytes to encode the color+on/off state, that's 12×10×3=360 bytes for everything.

Comment: Why do you need to send the index at all? Just send all the LEDs in order.